# Google Sites API PUT request giving status code 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: python, google-api, python-requests, google-sites

I created a page on sites.google.com with the name as [nastyusb12345](https://sites.google.com/site/nastyusb12345/).

Sending a PUT request results in the status code 400 (Bad Request)

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Nov 23 2017, 11:34:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> g = requests.get("https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/site/nastyusb12345/")
>>> g.status_code
200
>>> # to convert the byte stream returned by g.content to str i use .decode("utf-8") on the former one
... 
>>> # using the link for the put request given in the LINK tag with rel attribute as 'edit'
... 
>>> p = requests.put("https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/site/nastyusb12345/8957364112836929772", g.content.decode("utf-8"))
>>> p.status_code
400
```

I have extensively searched their guides and references which are given [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/).
Thanks in advance.

## Edit 1

The site that I have created is a Classic Site.

Comment: and you read the red text at the top of the documentation?

Comment: @DamTo Yes. I added that info to address the problem you pointed out.